# How to make the association's keys viewable by opener in input cell in editable form?

Tags: front-end, associations, inputfield

I have an association as follows (the actual association has hundreds of keys):

```
dataset=<|
    "CL"-><|
        "Frequency"->{{"06H2"}->1,{"13H2"}->1,{"19H1"}->1},
        "Severity"->{{"07H2","08H1","08H2"}->1,{"14H1"}->1},
        "LossCost"->{{"06H1"}->1,{"10H1","10H2","11H1"}->1,{"15H1","15H2","16H1"}->1,{"18H2","19H1","19H2"}->1}
    |>,
    "DCPD"-><|
        "Frequency"->{{"13H2"}->1,{"17H2"}->1,{"20H1"}->0},
        "Severity"->{{"14H2","15H1","15H2","16H1","16H2"}->1,{"20H1"}->0,{"22H1"}->0},
        "LossCost"->{{"13H2"}->1}
    |>,
    "ME"-><|
        "Frequency"->{{"13H2"}->1,{"16H1"}->1,{"19H1","19H2","20H1"}->1},
        "Severity"->{{"04H1"}->1,{"09H2"}->1,{"12H1"}->1,{"15H2"}->1,{"19H2"}->0,{"21H1"}->0},
        "LossCost"->{{"05H1"}->1,{"14H2"}->1,{"20H1","20H2","21H1"}->0}
    |>
|>;
```

This is not an output but an input inside an input cell that gets used in various places. My issue is, is there a way I can have only snippets of this association visible that I want to edit? Only some keys at a time.

I want the input to look like this while the value still editable.

[image]

When I click the opener, it should show the key-value pair in completely editable form, and clicking again it collapses.

When I evaluate the cell, the actual association should get stored in the dataset. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Sure definitely doable, but a pain. You'd be best off doing it with a `TemplateBox`-based construction with `Editable->True` and you'll need to be able to reparse the generated boxes again after editing to turn them into a proper dataset. The initial layout step is almost trivial at least, so I'd start with that direction. If you register the `TemplateBox` in a sylesheet, too, you can reuse this structure anywhere